# Why does shell/bash commands show strange behaviour in Google Collaboratory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, google-colaboratory

I am using a set of bash shells and Python3 shells in my Google Collab notebook.
Usually, the bash scripts and shell commands are executed as

```sh
!wget "somelink"
```

but I noticed that at times the change directory instruction`!cd /content/`
usually seems to work but in most cases, but sometimes, it requires `%cd /content/`
I can't seem to know why does this happen. I can't provide a reproducible example but can say that this problem occurs after running shell scripts (file with `.sh` extension).

Another strange behavior is: When I run a bash script, usually it can be done as `!script.sh` but when I edit the script or tried to replace it, I get the

```
/bin/bash: script.sh: Permission denied
```

Though [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151867/running-sh-script-permission-denied-despite-the-executable-bit-and-root-right) answer helped me get it work by using
`!bash script.sh`

How can I understand this behaviour?

Comment: the script is not executable? that's is the error you will get on all unix like system afaik.

Comment: I request to know the reason behind it for Collab, be it common to all Linux systems. Btw, Google Collab also works on a Ubuntu backend.